# Optimizing Nested Queries and Joins

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

I have a Query that I know works by running it on a single customer account. However, when I open it up to query all accounts, It becomes very slow. I haven't found a post that leads me to any improvements of the script.

I will post the script below. I don't have a specific question, but am wondering if there is any optimization improvements that can be made to increase the speed of this query?

```
select 

  count ( distinct abc.OrderNo) as Total_Orders,
  sum (case when abc.ItemDescription_Detail = 'Hi-Res Digital Image'then 1 else 0 end) as Total_DIDs,
  count (distinct  (case when abc.ItemDescription_Detail = 'Hi-Res Digital Image'  then abc.OrderNo end ))  as Total_DID_Orders,
  sum (case when abc.ItemDescription_Detail = 'CD High and Low Resolution'then 1 else 0 end) as Total_CD_Looks,
  count (distinct  (case when abc.ItemDescription_Detail = 'CD High and Low Resolution'  then abc.OrderNo end ))  as Total_CD_Orders, 

  sum (case when abc.ItemDescription_Detail = 'Hi-Res Digital Image' and abc.NORMALPKGFLAG = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as Total_PKG_DIDs,
  count (distinct  (case when abc.ItemDescription_Detail = 'Hi-Res Digital Image' and abc.NORMALPKGFLAG = '1' then abc.OrderNo end ))  as Total_PKG_DID_Orders,
  sum (case when abc.ItemDescription_Detail = 'CD High and Low Resolution' and abc.NORMALPKGFLAG = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as Total_PKG_CD_Looks,
  count (distinct  (case when abc.ItemDescription_Detail = 'CD High and Low Resolution' and abc.NORMALPKGFLAG = '1' then abc.OrderNo end ))  as Total_PKG_CD_Orders, 

  sum (case when abc.ItemDescription_Detail = 'Hi-Res Digital Image' and abc.SPECIALFLAG = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as Total_SPL_OFFER_DIDs,
  count (distinct  (case when abc.ItemDescription_Detail = 'Hi-Res Digital Image' and abc.SPECIALFLAG = '1' then abc.OrderNo end ))  as Total_SPL_OFFER_DID_Orders,
  sum (case when abc.ItemDescription_Detail = 'CD High and Low Resolution' and abc.SPECIALFLAG = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as Total_SPL_OFFER_CD_Looks,
  count (distinct  (case when abc.ItemDescription_Detail = 'CD High and Low Resolution' and abc.SPECIALFLAG = '1' then abc.OrderNo end ))  as Total_SPL_OFFER_CD_Orders, 

  sum (case when abc.ItemDescription_Detail = 'Hi-Res Digital Image' and abc.CREATEPKG = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as Total_CYOP_DIDs,
  count (distinct  (case when abc.ItemDescription_Detail = 'Hi-Res Digital Image' and abc.CREATEPKG = '1' then abc.OrderNo end ))  as Total_CYOP_DID_Orders,
  sum (case when abc.ItemDescription_Detail = 'CD High and Low Resolution' and abc.CREATEPKG = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as Total_CYOP_CD_Looks,
  count (distinct  (case when abc.ItemDescription_Detail = 'CD High and Low Resolution' and abc.CREATEPKG = '1' then abc.OrderNo end ))  as Total_CYOP_CD_Orders, 

  sum (case when abc.ItemDescription_Detail = 'Hi-Res Digital Image' and abc.CREATEPKG <> '1' and abc.SPECIALFLAG <> '1' and abc.NORMALPKGFLAG <> '1' then 1 else 0 end) as Total_Not_PKG_DIDs,
  count (distinct  (case when abc.ItemDescription_Detail = 'Hi-Res Digital Image' and abc.CREATEPKG <> '1' and abc.SPECIALFLAG <> '1' and abc.NORMALPKGFLAG <> '1' then abc.OrderNo end ))  as Total_Not_PKG_DID_Orders,
  sum (case when abc.ItemDescription_Detail = 'CD High and Low Resolution' and abc.CREATEPKG <> '1' and abc.SPECIALFLAG <> '1' and abc.NORMALPKGFLAG <> '1' then 1 else 0 end) as Total_Not_PKG_CD_Looks,
  count (distinct  (case when abc.ItemDescription_Detail = 'CD High and Low Resolution' and abc.CREATEPKG <> '1' and abc.SPECIALFLAG <> '1' and abc.NORMALPKGFLAG <> '1' then abc.OrderNo end ))  as Total_Not_PKG_CD_Orders 

from (select
        distinct
        oh.Event_Ref_ID,
        --oc.CHANNEL_NAME,
        oh.Order_Header_OID OrderHeader,
        oh.Order_No OrderNo,
        oh.Order_Date OrderDate,
        ol.Order_Line_OID OrderLine,
        ol.Unit_Price UnitPrice,
        ol.Ordered_Quantity Qty,
        --ol.List_Price ListPrice,
        --ol.Line_Total LineTotal,
        --ol.Est_Pretax_Amount EstPreTaxAmount,
        ------old.Order_Line_Detail_OID OrderLineDetail,
        ------old.Sheet_Size SheetSize,
        i.SKU_Category,
        i.Description ItemDescription,
        bi.SKU_Category SKUCategory_Detail,
        bi.Description ItemDescription_Detail,
        --ole.LookID,
        --bole.LookID,
        case when i.sku_category = 'PACKAGE' and i.Description  like '%Special%' then 1 else 0 end as SpecialFlag,
        case when i.sku_category = 'PACKAGE' and i.Description  like '%Create%' then 1 else 0 end as CreatePKG,
        case when i.sku_category = 'PACKAGE' and i.Description  not like '%Special%' and i.Description  not like '%Create%' then 1 else 0 end as NormalPKGFlag,
        case when bole.LookID IS NOT NULL  then bole.LookID else ole.LookID end as LookIDV2,
        Round (case when i.sku_category = 'PACKAGE' then ((ol.line_total) / (count(*) over (partition by ol.Order_Line_OID))) else (case when ol.line_total = '0' then ol.List_Price else ol.line_total end)  end, 2) as LINETOTAL,
        Round (case when i.sku_category = 'PACKAGE' then ((ol.Est_Pretax_Amount) / (count(*) over (partition by ol.Order_Line_OID))) else ol.Est_Pretax_Amount end, 2) as EST_PRE_TAX_LINETOTAL
        --count(*) over (partition by ol.Order_Line_OID) TotalinPKG

from (select * from ODS_OWN.ORDER_HEADER oh 
        where 
                EXISTS (select * from ODS_OWN.EVENT e where e.School_Year = 2019 and e.EVENT_REF_ID = oh.EVENT_REF_ID)
                and
                EXISTS (select * from ODS_OWN.ORDER_CHANNEL oc where CHANNEL_NAME = 'MLT' and oh.ORDER_CHANNEL_OID = oc.ORDER_CHANNEL_OID)

        ) oh


--inner join (select distinct ORDER_CHANNEL_OID, CHANNEL_NAME from ODS_OWN.ORDER_CHANNEL where CHANNEL_NAME = 'MLT') oc on oh.ORDER_CHANNEL_OID = oc.ORDER_CHANNEL_OID -- 
inner join ODS_OWN.APO apo on apo.APO_OID = oh.APO_OID
left join ODS_OWN.ORDER_LINE ol on oh.ORDER_HEADER_OID =  ol.ORDER_HEADER_OID
left join ODS_OWN.ORDER_LINE_DETAIL olde on ol.ORDER_LINE_OID = olde.ORDER_LINE_OID
left join ODS_OWN.ITEM i on ol.ITEM_OID = i.ITEM_OID
left join ODS_OWN.ORDER_LINE bol ON (ol.ORDER_LINE_OID = bol.BUNDLE_PARENT_ORDER_LINE_OID)
left join ODS_OWN.ITEM bi ON (bol.ITEM_OID = bi.ITEM_OID)
left join ODS_OWN.ORDER_LINE_DETAIL bold ON (bol.ORDER_LINE_OID = bold.ORDER_LINE_OID)
left join (select 
                ORDER_LINE_DETAIL_OID, 
                SUBSTR(ALIAS_ID,instr(alias_ID,' ')+1,LENGTH(ALIAS_ID)) as LookID
        from ODS_OWN.ORDER_LINE_ELEMENT
        where length(trim(alias_id)) > 0) ole on olde.ORDER_LINE_DETAIL_OID = ole.ORDER_LINE_DETAIL_OID
left join (select 
                ORDER_LINE_DETAIL_OID, 
                SUBSTR(ALIAS_ID,instr(alias_ID,' ')+1,LENGTH(ALIAS_ID)) as LookID
        from ODS_OWN.ORDER_LINE_ELEMENT 
        where length(trim(alias_id)) > 0) bole on bold.ORDER_LINE_DETAIL_OID = bole.ORDER_LINE_DETAIL_OID

where
ol.list_price != 0) abc
```

Comment: Questions about query performance ALWAYS require, as a minimum, CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables, and the results of the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Comment: (I would also be tempted to start with something a bit simpler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a starting point I'd try and get rid of some of the nesting.

For example:-

```
(select * from ODS_OWN.ORDER_HEADER oh 
        where 
                EXISTS (select * from ODS_OWN.EVENT e where e.School_Year = 2019 and e.EVENT_REF_ID = oh.EVENT_REF_ID)
                and
                EXISTS (select * from ODS_OWN.ORDER_CHANNEL oc where CHANNEL_NAME = 'MLT' and oh.ORDER_CHANNEL_OID = oc.ORDER_CHANNEL_OID)

        ) oh
```

Could that be pre-run into a temporary or variable table? then you could reference it directly rather than having the query run for each row to get the same data. Additionally, I would cite the columns rather than using *. It may be that there are no additional columns, but naming them is usually quicker.

Similarly these two subqueries:-

```
left join (select 
                ORDER_LINE_DETAIL_OID, 
                SUBSTR(ALIAS_ID,instr(alias_ID,' ')+1,LENGTH(ALIAS_ID)) as LookID
        from ODS_OWN.ORDER_LINE_ELEMENT
        where length(trim(alias_id)) > 0) ole on olde.ORDER_LINE_DETAIL_OID = ole.ORDER_LINE_DETAIL_OID
left join (select 
                ORDER_LINE_DETAIL_OID, 
                SUBSTR(ALIAS_ID,instr(alias_ID,' ')+1,LENGTH(ALIAS_ID)) as LookID
        from ODS_OWN.ORDER_LINE_ELEMENT 
        where length(trim(alias_id)) > 0) bole on bold.ORDER_LINE_DETAIL_OID = bole.ORDER_LINE_DETAIL_OID
```

are likely to be costly as they are dealing with string manipulation. If they could be pre-run again into a temporary table, variable table or even as a CTE, it is likely to improve performance.